# c++ link list remove all method is leaving last element unremoved

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have developed a function to remove all nodes from linked list. All nodes are successfully deleted except the last one. Please help me why last node is not being deleted? Following is my code:

```
void StudentLinkList::removeAll() {
    StudentData *traversePointer = this->head;

    while (this->head->getNext() != nullptr) {
        this->head = this->head->getNext();
        delete traversePointer;
        traversePointer = this->head;
    }

    delete this->head;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to test if this->head is null or not.

Comment: Probably voted down because you didn't show anything you tried to fix this on your own.

Comment: Make a `remove` function if you don't already have one. Keep calling the `remove` function until the `is_empty` function (you have on of those, right?) returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're deleting this->head, but you should set this->head to nullptr as well. While you're freeing the memory the node is using, the data stored in the node's old location usually isn't immediately overwritten, which is why it looks like the last node is not deleted.

EDIT: downvote is duly noted, could someone clarify what I got wrong?

Also, I agree with the above comment - you should also check if this->head is null before the loop.

Comment: Brilliant. Setting it to nullptr worked. Can you provide any documentation where it says that the data stored in the node's old location usually isn't immediately overwritten? is it a rule in c++ or bug?

Comment: Well it wouldn't be in documentation since technically speaking, it's not what's supposed to happen. For efficiency though, memory allocators usually tend not to overwrite data when freeing memory because allocators aren't explicitly required to reset data that's freed. This is why you need to zero-initialize arrays that you create in C. I would avoid using any data after it is freed, because your compiler could choose to explicitly reset freed memory blocks to, say, all 0s. But also, even if the memory is overwritten, this->head would still be a pointer to an unallocated memory region.

Comment: Basically, memory allocated to a program is usually reused after free next time you allocate a memory block near the size of the one that was freed.

Comment: Not quite right.  Suppose it is called with an empty list?

Comment: @stark Refer to my edit. You have a valid point. But, while that is a bug, it isn't what caused the bug that OP was asking about.

Comment: @stark and Anish, Answers from both of you helped me to understand the overall issue. Thanks for your time guys

Answer (score 1):

So close

```
void StudentLinkList::removeAll() {
    StudentData *traversePointer;

    // Continue while there are any elements on the list
    // Extra parens to indicate that we want the result of the 
    // assignment as boolean.  No need to compare to nullptr.
    while ( (traversePointer = this->head) ) {
        // First preserve the rest of the list
        this->head = this->head->getNext();
        // only then can we delete this node
        delete traversePointer;
    }
    // list is now empty
}
```

Comment: That's a nice way. Just wondering that I am deleting all the nodes in my code. Despite of that why it was not working.

Comment: You were testing next element instead of current element.  Think of all the special cases: empty list, 1-element list, etc.

Comment: yes you are right. It will crash in case of empty list.